# Does PostgreSQL guarantes unicity of `commit timestamp` for two simultaneous commits?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, transactional, postgresql-9.5

**Context :** I expose an API that provides only the new stuff presents in a PostgreSQL table. "New" means added since the last call.

To do that, I have switched on the `track_commit_timestamp` option defined into my PostgreSQL server and ordered table content by this commit date. It works well.

To provide the new stuff, I keep the most recent commit timestamp presents on my SQL select response and uses it to build the next request like a starting point (date >= to this value).

But, I have a question about this mechanism (`track_commit_timestamp`) : Is it possible for 2 simultaneous commits to have the same timestamp and are not "visibles" at the same moment ? And so, if my "SQL select" request is executed during this small interval I lost the second transaction content ?

Comment: I can't find anything in the docs that says the transaction timestamp is intended or guaranteed to be unique. To me, it wouldn't make sense if Postgres had to pause between transactions to guarantee their microseconds would be unique. Nor does it seem right that the clock would be advanced incrementally by microseconds just to give unique TS to simultaneous transactions. That's what the TX ID is for. Just some thoughts. Hope this helps.

Comment: It depends on the granularity of the timestamp values and the speed of insertion. If the database is fast enough it could insert two records with identical timestamps due to a lack of precision.

Comment: @tadman I think you have reason, timestamp presition isn't enough :(

Comment: @VictorDiLeo I agree with you. But uses the TX id is not the solution to resolve my use case because this ID is genereted when transaction begins and not at the commit. So it's possible to have a transaction content commited with lower TX id after an transaction content with greater.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think "simultaneous" makes sense here.

Imagine two transactions writing to your database (A,B) and one reading from it (C).

```
time------------>
  A->|
  B------------>|
       C-->|
```

Now, (C) will of course see A with a timestamp of T1. B also has a timestamp of T1 but hasn't committed yet. As a result, C can't see it since it may be rolled back.

So, you can only reliably access data for transactions that completed before C started. The latest viable timestamp is just before the oldest concurrent transaction.

There are two simplifications that might help you and one alternative approach.

Firstly, if all your transactions are short (say under 1 second) then you simply subtract 1 second from your transaction's start time and read changes older than that. This is actually quite commonly workable.

Secondly, if concurrency is not a concern you can enforce serialisation perhaps with transaction levels or through an explicit lock.

The alternative is to stop worrying about timestamps and instead consider your situation as a stream of changes. This would be the approach taken by various trigger-based replication systems or the logical replication supported as an add-on in 9.5(?) onwards and natively in version 10.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I will choose the explicit lock solution coupled with an auto increment primary key, so the primary key order and the data insertion (and makes visible to others transactions) order are the sames.